# Network of medical treatment comparisons per disease

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a data set that would contain one network of comparisons between medical treatment, for each medical condition.

For example, for lateral epicondylitis (lateral epicondylopathy), one network of comparisons between medical treatments could be:

[image]

( example taken from Krogh, T., E. M. Bartels, T. Ellingsen, K. Stengaard-Pedersen, R. Buchbinder, U. Fredberg, H. Bliddal, and R. Christensen. "OP0072 Comparative effectiveness of injection therapies in lateral epicondylitis: A systematic review and network meta-analysis of randomized controlled trials." Annals of the Rheumatic Diseases 71, no. Suppl 3 (2013): 77-78. [link](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Comparative+effectiveness+of+injection+therapies+in+lateral+epicondylitis%3A+a+systematic+review+and+network+meta-analysis+of+randomized+controlled+trials&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C22&as_sdtp=)  )

I am mostly interested in randomized controlled trials.